# What is events in Otto and are there types of events that could be published using OTTO?

Tags: events, bus, otto

Iam just a bit confused with what type of events can be published through OTTO. and a example of event class will be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can publish any objects. Check the Otto [home page](http://square.github.io/otto/). There you see an example where `AnswerAvailableEvent` event gets published. Event class can look like this.

```
public class AnswerAvailableEvent {
    private int answer;

    public AnswerAvailableEvent(int answer) {
      this.answer = answer;
    }

    public int getAnswer() {
      return answer;
    }
}
```